# weird behaviour with forever, bash, apache and php

Tags: linux, bash, apache-http-server, php, node.js

I'm running some node.js scripts with `forever`.

I started them as `www-data` user (i.e. via ssh logging as www-data@server and typing `forever start myapp.js`, etc.).

Ok, everything goes like a charm; my application works as expected, and typing `forever list` shows me the processes running.

Then, I wrote a (very simple) script named `foreverList.sh` and placed in folder `/var/www/scripts/` :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "checking running node.js scripts:"
forever list
```

When I execute the script from shell as `www-data` user, it works. Nothing fancy here. But, this script is to be used with PHP 5.6 through Apache 2.4, with :

```
<?php
// ....
$resp_script = shell_exec("/var/www/scripts/foreverList.sh 2>&1");
echo "<pre>$resp_script</pre>";
```

And when I execute it via my web browser (so with the PHP code above), it doesn't work!! I get this `forever` error message (nodejs, not php):

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:674
procs.forEach(function (proc) {
^
TypeError: Object Error: EACCES, permission denied '/root/.forever/sock' has no method 'forEach'
...
... #(stack trace follows)
```

I really don't understand why it deals with /root folder, as I'm running all this stuff from /var/www/ folder and as `www-data` user (added a `whoami` in the script to check it was the case, and it does).

Do I miss something? Is it a forever bug?

Any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE** : I tried to add `echo $HOME` in the bash script, and it returns nothing. Does PHP itself erase the home path environment variable of `www-data` user?

Comment: That is just...weird.  except I believe php has a bit different syntax when it comes to permissions.

Comment: it has different wording.

Comment: Forever needs a store for the process info. Normally it's `~/.forever/`. Maybe (wild guess here) www-data doesn't have a homedir configured so it reverts to root's homedir? What's the homedir for your www-data user (try: `getent passwd www-data | cut -d: -f6`)? Do you use a config.json and are there some clues to this behaviour?

Comment: Thx. www-data has its own home dir, which is `/var/www`. It also has a `.forever` dir in there, with a `config.json` file and all logs files of the running processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution.

Actually, Apache unset the `$HOME` environment variable, (see line 4 of `/etc/apache2/envvar` file:  `unset HOME`)

The only thing to do was to add:

```
export HOME=/var/www
```

before the `forever list` line in the bash script.

And works like a charm.